# Dumping variables from lists ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfdump

I have this struct after I dump it like this:

`<cfdump var="#currentInfo.answers#">`

How can I access the value inside the `LIST`?

I need to compare that value with another variable in the future to allow me to do certain operations.

[image: Struct]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below ought to do it:

```
currentInfo.answers["F0FF5FDC-D2C3-4D0F-D7D2D2886D5B430d"].LIST
```

Comment: is that reference always the same? Or does it change based on what questions you're pulling?

Comment: it changes everytime, this is what I am trying to figure out now.

Comment: +1 it might be worth mentioning that you can use this bracket notation for the entire variable (as it is a struct). e.g  `currentInfo["answers"]["F0FFF....etc"]["list"]` - Both produce the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is dynamic you'll need something like this:

```
currentKey="F0FF5FDC-D2C3-4D0F-D7D2D2886D5B430d";
currentInfo.answers[currentKey].LIST;
```